Instance of toomanypagesexception in pdf flutter
I'm using pdf plugin and i able to show multiple pages pdf. Now the issue the data is coming from api and if the data on Text widget is in bulk information then i'm getting the exception 'toomanypagesexception'. It only works if i reduce the fontsize to 10 but text display is very small. Below is the sample dart code and please help me on this issue.
pdf package
class PdfPreviewWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Drugs drugs;
  const PdfPreviewWidget({super.key, required this.drugs});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: bodyColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
        centerTitle: false,
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: primaryColor,
        title: Text(
          preview,
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.0),
        ),
      ),
      body: PdfPreview(
        previewPageMargin: EdgeInsets.zero,
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        enableScrollToPage: true,
        canChangeOrientation: false,
        canChangePageFormat: false,
        canDebug: false,
        build: (context) => generatePdf(drugs),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<Uint8List> generatePdf(Drugs drugs) async {
  final pdf = pw.Document();
  var data = await rootBundle.load('assets/Amiri-Regular.ttf');
  final ttf = pw.Font.ttf(data);
  pdf.addPage(pw.MultiPage(
      textDirection: pw.TextDirection.rtl,
      build: (context) {
        return [
          pw.ListView.builder(
              itemCount: drugs.details!.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return pw.Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    pw.Text(drugs.details![index]!.title ?? "",
                        style: pw.TextStyle(
                          font: ttf,
                          fontSize: 25.0,
                          fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold,
                          color: const PdfColor.fromInt(0xFF259cd8),
                        ),
                        textDirection: pw.TextDirection.rtl),
                    pw.SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                    pw.Column(
                        children: drugs.details![index]!.details!.map((e) {
                      return pw.Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          pw.Padding(
                            padding: const pw.EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                            child: pw.Container(
                              height: 5.0,
                              width: 5.0,
                              decoration: const pw.BoxDecoration(
                                color: PdfColor.fromInt(0xFF000000),
                                borderRadius: pw.BorderRadius.all(
                                    pw.Radius.circular(2.0)),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          pw.SizedBox(
                            width: 10.0,
                          ),
                          pw.Expanded(
                              child: pw.Text(e!,
                                  style: pw.TextStyle(font: ttf, fontSize: 16),
                                  textDirection: pw.TextDirection.rtl)), // Exception on this line
                        ],
                      );
                    }).toList()),
                    pw.SizedBox(height: 25.0),
                  ],
                );
              }),
        ];
      }));
  return pdf.save();
} 

